# How can I get only domains using the python script below?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am able to get all the URLs in the search page using the script below

```
import requests
import bs4
import re

text= "online+astrology"
url = 'https://google.com/search?q=' + text

request_result=requests.get( url )

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(request_result.text,"html.parser")

for link in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("https://")}):
  print(link.get('href'))
```

Using the above script I'm able to get the links below

```
https://maps.google.com/maps?q=online+astrology&um=1&ie=UTF-8&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjL3e-K_uX_AhXNATQIHf8IBk4Q_AUICSgE
/url?q=https://www.astrosage.com/&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwjL3e-K_uX_AhXNATQIHf8IBk4QFnoECAkQAg&usg=AOvVaw0V7KGYoF_WyIaSpOEXkrVU
```

And I'm unable to find the way to get only domains from the list above.

Example:

```
astrosage.com
astrotalk.com
```

Could anyone please help me to solve the above issue and to remove duplicates from the list?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the domains are hidden in google's relative links query parameter, we can use regex to extract the domain between https:// and the next /

```
reg = re.search(r"https://([^/]*)/", link.get('href'))
if reg is not None:
    domain = reg.group(1)
    print(domain)
```

To then filter out duplicates we can use a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets). For example:

```
domains = set()
for link in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("https://")}):
    reg = re.search(r"https://([^/]*)/", link.get('href'))
    if reg is not None:
        domains.add(reg.group(1))
print(list(domains))
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use [urllib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html):

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse


for link in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("https://")}):
    domain = urlparse(link.get('href')).netloc
    print(domain)
```

Answer (score 0):

Only change last line:

```
print(link.get('href').split('//')[1].split('/')[0])
```